# Does anyone know why my Maps aren't showing up in my app?

Tags: android, grid, maps

I am using a debugging key for my API. I have generated it about 10 times now out of desperation.

Here's my Java code:

```
public class MyMap extends MapActivity {

private MapView mapView;
private MapController mc;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_map);

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    }
}
```

Here's the XML layout file:

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:apiKey="0UsP9tzCZAIzw2b76-QktRuiZKaDt59u6ySX09w" android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:clickable="true" android:enabled="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And here's my manifest file:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">

    <activity android:name=".MyMap" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="1" />
```

I just keep getting the grid. I haven't got a clue why. I have been at this for hours now. Also, I have done this with a release key, made an APK and still the same problem.

Can anyone help?

**SOLVED**:

I had my MapActivity inside an ActivityGroup and for some reason the maps won't load like that. I simply took the map out of the ActivityGroup, loaded it as it's own Intent and it worked fine. Weird problem. Google should get on sorting that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you also have to implement this method to conform to the use of the maps API:

```
@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed()
{       
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I should have added that code to my question because I had it in. Sorry. I solved the problem though. For some reason my MapActiviy didn't work inside an ActivityGroup. Tis weird but it's solved now. Thanks.